# calling web service built in .net 2 from application built in .net 1.1

Tags: .net, web-services

is there a problem calling web service built in .net 2 from application built in .net 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webservices are described by WSDL (Web Service Description Language) language for the outside world. WSDL is the same and is independent of the .NET framework.

So you should be able to call the service without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

**No problem at all.** Even if you call 2.0 WebServices from other programming languages (as PHP or Java) it will work.

The webservices uses a XML to communicate (defined in WSDL), so the client (Whatever) and the server(webservice in 2.0) do not need to be the same platform... only need to use same XML data.